# How to print array of specific item

Tags: php, database, array

I have get the following array from my database using mysql query in PHP. What is way to print the specific item (e.g: `staff_name` and `coupon`)?

```
{"items":[{"ca_id":1,"appointment_date":"2018-07-02 08:00:00","service_name":"Eye check-up","service_price":50,"service_tax":0,"wait_listed":false,"deposit_format":null,"number_of_persons":"1","units":"1","duration":"3600","staff_name":"Mc Miltony","extras":[]}],"coupon":null,"subtotal":{"price":50,"deposit":0},"customer":"Mr Jhon","tax_in_price":"excluded","tax_paid":"5.00"}
```

Comment: Where is this data in your database? How does that JSON you posted relate to the database structure? What does this have to do with WordPress? Please take a moment to review the "[ask]" page in our [help], and then consider filing an [edit] to improve your question.

Comment: This data came from a WordPress plugin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not really a WordPress question, but I'll bite.

That data is [JSON](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Objects/JSON). To manipulate it with PHP you need to decode it with [`json_decode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php). Then you can treat it as a PHP object.

So to access the values you'd mention, and assuming the JSON is in a variable named `$json`:

```
$object = json_decode( $json );
$staff_name = $object->items[0]->staff_name;
$coupon = $object->coupon;
```

Comment: I was little bit confused about the array. But, thanks a lot.

Answer (score -3):

```
<?php
$results = '{"items":[{"ca_id":1,"appointment_date":"2018-07-02 08:00:00","service_name":"Eye check-up","service_price":50,"service_tax":0,"wait_listed":false,"deposit_format":null,"number_of_persons":"1","units":"1","duration":"3600","staff_name":"Mc Miltony","extras":[]}],"coupon":null,"subtotal":{"price":50,"deposit":0},"customer":"Mr Jhon","tax_in_price":"excluded","tax_paid":"5.00"}';
$object = json_decode( $results );
$staff_name = $object->items[0]->staff_name;
$coupon = $object->coupon;
?>
```

Comment: It does not work.